# sbt subProject: dependsOn

Tags: scala, sbt

I have the following build.sbt with two sub projects. Everything compiles and runs fine.
One is a thin scala play project. `dataextractor` has a lot of util classes I want to call in the `play` project.

However, the configurarion below still leads to the following compilation error:

> [error]
>   /Users/foo.bar/_vws/com.corp.enablement.scripts/sirf_extract_serve/tools_sirf_server/app/corp/tools/es_result_server/service/SystemInitializer.scala:6:21:
>   object dataextraction is not a member of package corp.tools [error]
>   import corp.tools.dataextraction.providers.confluence

This is my first sbt multi-project. Advice would be genuinley appreciated

```
lazy val tools_dataextractor = (project in file("tools_dataextractor")).settings(
  Defaults.itSettings,
  libraryDependencies += scalatest % "it,test",
  name := "corp_tools_dataextractor",
  version := "0.1",
  mainClass in Compile := Some("corp.tools.ExtractionStartUp")
  )

lazy val tools_sirf_server = (project in file("tools_sirf_server")).settings(

  ).enablePlugins(PlayScala).dependsOn(tools_dataextractor)


lazy val root = (project in file("."))
    .aggregate(tools_dataextractor, tools_sirf_server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, the answer is neophyte error.
I had a `build.sbt` in the root and a `build.sbt` in each sub project (which is permissible).

Everything will built fine.... Until I started adding dependencies from one sub-project to another. In this case, the super `build.sbt` "`dependsOn`" is ignored and compilation errors occur.

Side note, the main reason for keeping sub-project `build.sbt` was simply laziness. It took half a day to get everything working in a single `build.sbt` at the root level. However, it is defintiely worth the effort.

Answer (score 1):

The configuration looks good.

2 possibilities what the problem might be:

- You are in a `sbt-console` and haven't reloaded the console after you changed `build.sbt`
- You work with Intellij and did not reload the `sbt projects`

If this does not help - adjust your question with the steps you take.

Comment: These are legitimate suggestions, but did not solve things in my case